# Django Models - Lists vs One-to-Many

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, django-models

I have two models, `Audience` and `Reports`, that I want to relate. The Audience model has one set of ids that reference a particular instance of an audience while the reports have a separate set of codes that relate to a particular instance of an audience. On top of that each report is associated with multiple Audience.

Am still pretty new to Django but just ashamedly rusty with setting up database models.

In my current solution I create a third model `AudienceReportMapping` which just relates the `audience_id` to the `report_code`. I have a class method on Reports which uses the intermediate mapping table to get me the appropriate audience ids for the codes associated with each report. Everything relevant is set up like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql import ListTestField

class Audience(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.IntegerField()


class AudienceReportMapping(models.Model):
    audience = models.ForeignKey(Audience)
    report_code = models.IntegerField()


class Reports(models.Model):
    ...
    report_id = models.IntegerField()
    codes = ListTextField(
        base_field=models.IntegerField()
    )

    @classmethod
    def audience_ids(cls, report_id):
        report = Reports.objects.filter(report_id=report_id).first()
        codes = report.codes
        audience_ids = []
        for code in codes:
            audience = AudienceReportMapping.objects.filter(report_code=code).first().audience
            audiences_ids.append(audience.id)
        return audience_ids
```

This feels like a pretty inelegant solution to something thats been solved before, just have trouble getting my head around Model set up. Is there a better way I could be doing this?

More specifically it feels like I should be able to set up a relation directly in the model definition rather than having a class method to determine the proper ids. The necessity of mapping ids to codes I think is the thing that's confusing me.

`#------- Edit --------#`

After some thought, it seems like I want to have a new property on the Audience model of `report_code`, since this is one-to-one and then have `audiences = models.ForeignKey(Audience)` on the Reports models to make a one-to-many mapping of audiences to reports. And completely scrap the AudienceReportMapping.

Comment: I'm assuming: Each Audience can belong to multiple Reports, via an intermediary AudienceReportMapping that assigns a code to each relationship. If so, this might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships. In the example, Audience is Person, Report is Group and AudienceReportMapping is Membership.

Comment: If, as your edit seems to say, each Audience has a unique report_code, and belongs to a single Report, the easiest thing would be something like putting `report_code = models.IntegerField()` and `report = models.ForeignKey(Report)` on the Audience model.

With that, you can find all Audience objects from a Report instance with: `report.audience_set.all()`

Comment: Also, do read up on `filter` vs `get`. :) `filter(id=id).first()` will get you the first matching object, or None. In the very next line you assume an object was found, though, which will raise an error if it doesn't exist. Also, if you data gets corrupted and you end up with multiple entries with the same id, this would go unnoticed. `get(id=id)` however will raise an error both if no such object exists, as well as if multiple matches are found. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Each `Audience ID` has a single `Report Code` but a Report can have many IDs/Codes. IDs/Codes can belong to many Reports. The IDs and Codes are essentially the same thing, they reference the same object just in different contexts. I just start with Codes and want to get to IDs!

Comment: But can an Audience ID belong to multiple Reports? If no, make a ForeignKey from Audience to Report, retrieve all audiences for a report with `report.audience_set.all()`. If yes, make a ManyToMany called `audiences` from Report to Audience, get the list with `report.audiences.all()`. (Note that your suggestion, "`audiences = models.ForeignKey(Audience)` on the Reports models to make a one-to-many mapping of audiences to reports." will not work, since that means "audiences" will be a *single* record. However, each audience will potentially have multiple records through the reverse relation.)

Comment: Definitely the latter, will check it out thanks!

Comment: Read through an example of many to many... seems I have overcomplicated the matter but does make so much sense now, thanks Björn!